# How do I make all equations in a document not italic?

Tags: macos, ms-office

Word makes all my equations italic.

Is there a way to make them non-italic so any current equation and future ones will be created with regular Cambria text?

I am using Word 16.17 on Mojave.

Comment: Another place to ask is https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Comment: Not a direct solution. I prefer to use Latex for my math typesetting. It looks a lot better and is really powerful.  Here are some templates. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates